# How to change background colour of WordPress admin page based on user role using php?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to change the background color of my WordPress menu based on user role. Everyone except admin should have the entire background yellow.

I want to select everyone below the level of administrator to have a yellow background.!

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook to `admin_head` and add custom CSS in admin page. If Admin then function will bail and will not add any CSS. Function `current_user_can()` can be used to check capabilities. Please check following example.

```
add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' );

function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
    // Bail if Admin.
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <style>
        body {background-color: #DED51F; }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That's great and it worked thanks but doesn't change the background color of top bar or side pop out menu bar...possible?

Comment: Now you need to add CSS after `<style>` tag. For example ` #wpadminbar { background-color: #DED51F; } #adminmenuback, #adminmenu { background-color: #DED51F; }`. Please debug admin panel in browser and add relegant CSS.

Comment: `<style>#wpadminbar { background-color: #DED51F; } #adminmenuback, #adminmenu { background-color: #DED51F; } </style>` in my head?

Comment: Or in functions.php like so `add_action( 'admin_head', 'wpso_add_admin_custom_css' );

function wpso_add_admin_custom_css() {
    // Bail if Admin.
    if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <style>
        body {background-color: #DED51F; }
#wpadminbar { background-color: #DED51F; } #adminmenuback, #adminmenu { background-color: #DED51F; }
    </style>
    <?php
}`?

Comment: OK. That worked for everything except see screenshot above

Comment: Poss to make black dissappear in menu?

Comment: Don't worry if you haven't got time or anything. I'll mark correct. Thanks for you answer.

Comment: it is not working for me, when do you need to call `admin_head`?